# How to re-use GoPortfolio portfolios for different categories, tags or post ids

Tags: wordpress

The [GoPortfolio Wordpress](http://codecanyon.net/item/go-responsive-portfolio-for-wp/5741904) plugin allows me to create beautiful, responsive image galleries - for Posts and for WooCommerce products but I find it very tedious that I have to clone a portfolio every time I wish to include some products or posts on a page.

GoPortfolio includes a shortcode which allows you to embed the portfolio anywhere on the page but for some reason it doesn't let you filter through the shortcode on categories, tags or post ids.

I've answered how to modify the plugin below to allow you to re-use portfolios for different posts, categories or tags.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the GoPortplugin code slightly so that the shortcode can handle categories, tags, posts parameters. That means I can create one Go portfolio for 1 style I like then re-use that portfolio multiple times.

I modified class_go_portfolio.php (version 1.5.0) with the following changes:

Line 1751:
            'exclude_posts' => '',
            'tags' => '',
            'posts' => '',
            'categories' => ''

Line 1831 (after you've added the 3 lines above):

```
                            /* Dave H modification of Plugin - this grabs tag slugs and filters to only those tag slugs*/
                            if ( isset( $tags ) && !empty( $tags ) ) {
                                $included_tags = explode(',', trim( $tags ) );
                                $new_wp_query_args['tag__in'] = $included_tags;
                            }                               
                            /* Dave H modification of Plugin - this grabs post ids and filters to only those post ids (can be used, e.g. to show 4 product items in a gallery type format) */
                            if ( isset( $posts ) && !empty( $posts) ) {
                                $included_posts = explode(',', trim( $posts ) );
                                $new_wp_query_args['post__in'] = $included_posts;
                            }                               
                            /* Dave H modification of Plugin - this grabs post ids and filters to only those post ids (can be used, e.g. to show 4 product items in a gallery type format) */
                            if ( isset( $categories ) && !empty( $categories) ) {
                                $included_categories = explode(',', trim( $categories ) );
                                $new_wp_query_args['category__in'] = $included_categories;
                            }
```

Finally, I updated the version number at the top of the file to 99 so it doesn't auto-update and overwrite my changes.